# page break in visualforce pdf after 10 records

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I need to modify the below page to generate a PDF and modify the PDF exporting settings to export a table of only 10 records on each page.

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetvar="Cont">
<head>
    <style>
        .head { font-size:1.3em; }
    </style>
</head>
<apex:slds />
<body>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <apex:form>
            <apex:sectionHeader title="Financial Force Contacts" subtitle="Financial Home" help="https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=contacts_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0" />
            <apex:panelGrid columns="6">
                <apex:outputLabel value="View:" />
                <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="sel">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!list}" />
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:commandButton value="GO!" action="{!list}" />
                <apex:outputLink value="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?id=00B6F00000Al7Mj&retURL=%2F003&cancelURL=%2F003%2Fo">
                    <apex:outputtext value="Edit"/>
                </apex:outputLink>|
                <apex:outputLink value="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?ui/list/FilterEditPage?ftype=c&retURL=%2F003&cancelURL=%2F003%2Fo">
                    <apex:outputtext value="Create New View"/>
                </apex:outputLink>
            </apex:panelGrid>

            <apex:pageBlock>
                <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="50%">
                    <h1 class="head">Recent Contacts</h1>
                    <apex:commandButton value="New" action="/001/e" />
                </apex:panelGrid>
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cont}" var="item"  id="list">
                    <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!item.id}">
                            <apex:outputText >{!item.name}</apex:outputText>
                        </apex:outputLink>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column headerValue="Account Name">
                        <apex:outputLink value="/{!item.accountid}">
                            <apex:outputtext value="{!item.Account.name}"/>
                        </apex:outputlink>
                    </apex:column>

                    <apex:column headerValue="Phone">
                        <apex:outputtext value="{!item.phone}"/>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>
    </div>
</body>
```

I used renderAs=pdf to generate the page in pdf which displays 20 records in a table.

To apply page break after 10 records, I tried with apex:repeat, div style="page-break-after:always; and apex:variable but it does not seem to work.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following code and it worked. For the benefit of readers, I am posting the below code:

```
    <apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardController="Contact" recordSetvar="Cont" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">

<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="print">
        .head {
            font-size: 1.3em;
        }

        @page {
            size: A4 landscape;

            @top-center {

                content: element(header);

            }

            size: 210mm 297mm;
            margin: 15mm;
            margin-right:0mm;

            margin-top: 4.215cm;
            margin-bottom: 2.80cm;
            margin-left: 1.27cm;
            margin-right:1cm;

            @bottom-left {
                content: element(footer);
            }

        }

        div.header {
            padding: 10px;
            position: running(header);
            height: 80px;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
        }

        div.footer {

            display: block;

            padding: 5px;

            position: running(footer);
            clear: both;
            margin-top: 15px;

        }

        .pagenumber:before {
            content: counter(page);
        }

        .pagecount:before {
            content: counter(pages);
        }


        .labelcls {
            margin-left: 100px;
            font-size: 15px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<apex:form >
    <div class="header" width="100%">
        <div>
            <apex:outputLabel styleclass="labelcls">Financial Force</apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-size:15px; margin-left:50px; margin-right:70px;" value="Financial Force">
            </apex:outputLabel>
            <apex:outputLabel style="font-size:15px; margin-left:100px; margin-right:30px;" value="Financial Force">
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
            </apex:outputLabel>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="footer" style="font-size:10px;">
        <p align="center">Page <span class="pagenumber" /> of <span class="pagecount" /></p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Financial Force Contacts" subtitle="Financial Home" help="https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?err=1&id=contacts_overview.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0" />
        <apex:panelGrid columns="6">
            <apex:outputLabel value="View:" />
            <apex:selectList value="{!filterId}" size="1" id="sel">
                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!list}" />
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!listviewoptions}" />
            </apex:selectList>
            <apex:commandButton value="GO!" action="{!list}" />
            <apex:outputLink value="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?id=00B6F00000Al7Mj&retURL=%2F003&cancelURL=%2F003%2Fo">
                <apex:outputtext value="Edit" />
            </apex:outputLink>|
            <apex:outputLink value="/ui/list/FilterEditPage?ui/list/FilterEditPage?ftype=c&retURL=%2F003&cancelURL=%2F003%2Fo">
                <apex:outputtext value="Create New View" />
            </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:panelGrid>

        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:variable value="{!1}" var="num" />
            <apex:panelGrid columns="2" width="50%">
                <h1 class="head">Recent Contacts</h1>
                <apex:commandButton value="New" action="/001/e" />
            </apex:panelGrid>

            <apex:repeat value="{!Cont}" var="item" id="list">

                <!-- -------------FOR PAGINATION START--------------- -->
                <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!num == 1  || num == 11 || num == 31 || num == 51 || num == 71 || num == 91 || num == 111 || num == 131}">

                    <table border="1" width="100%" rules="cols">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" width="40%">
                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold; ">Name</apex:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="25%">
                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold; ">Account Name</apex:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" width="25%">
                                <apex:outputLabel style="font-weight:bold;  ">Phone</apex:outputLabel>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </apex:outputpanel>


                <table width="100%" border="1" rules="cols">

                    <tr>
                        <!--<td align="left" width="10%">{!num}</td>-->
                        <td align="center" width="40%">{!item.name}</td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%">{!item.Account.name}</td>
                        <td align="center" width="25%">{!item.phone}</td>
                    </tr>

                </table>

                <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!num == 10 || num ==30  || num == 50 || num == 70 || num == 90 || num == 110 || num == 130 || num == 150}">
                    <!-- ----PAGENATION END -->

                    <div style="page-break-after: always;">&nbsp; </div>

                </apex:outputpanel>
                <apex:variable value="{!num+1}" var="num" />


            </apex:repeat>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </div>
</apex:form>
  </apex:page>
```